# Unique porting code from VBA to C# using an unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, vba, unmanaged, dllimport, porting

This would be a great challenge for someone with knowledge of VBA and unmanaged C#.

First, we have obtained a third party dll with little to no documentation on it's API use however we did obtain an Excel spreadsheet using the dll. The problem is when we tried porting the code over to C# things have gone from bad to worse. I have a funny feeling that we're missing one tiny thing...

Anyway the code from the spread sheet is as follows..

```
Declare Sub someFunction Lib "C:\somedll.dll" _
(types1 As TYPE1, _
vals1 As Double, vals2 As Double, _
type2 As TYPE2, type3 As TYPE3, types4 As TYPE4, _
vals3 As Double)

... 'Logic to fill in the arrays and create UDT's etc.

Call someFunction(types1(0), vals1(0), vals2(0), _
type2, type3, types4(0), vals3(0))
```

Option Explicit is set so all arrays are dimensioned or "Dim" and they are using UDT for things like TYPE1, TYPE2 etc.

The issue now is when I port over to C# I do not get the expected results as I see in VBA.

My C# code is as follows...

```
    [DllImport("c:\somedll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    private static extern void someFunction( ref TYPE1[] types1,
                                               ref double[] vals1,
                                               ref double[] vals2,
                                               TYPE2 type2,
                                               TYPE3 type3,
                                               ref TYPE4[] types4,
                                               ref double[] vals3);

 ...

 //in a method after all arrays are initialized etc 

 someFunction(ref types1, ref vals1, ref vals2, type2, type3, ref types4, ref vals3);

 // PInvoke function 'someFunction' has an unbalanced stack. Signatures are off etc.
```

Problem is the code is almost identical to VBA minus the Arrays not being dynamic and structures in C# defined using marshaling. Here's an example of a struct ...

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
 public class TYPE3
 {
    public double t1;
    public double t2;
    public double t3;
 }
```

Also I noted that the all the arrays passed in VBA version are being manipulated even though you are passing in the index (0) of the array. Could this have to do with them passing the pointer to the array in VBA?

Anyway, this has really been confusing me as of lately as I have tried everything including pointers (IntPtr) etc.

Even tried calling the dll from C++. But that presented a whole new slew of problems that I won't discuss here.

Comment: I wonder what the suicide rate is at your workplace...

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think your prototype can be correct.  If it is a ThisCall the first argument should be     a reference to the object you are calling the method on... so either it isn't a this call or your first parameter isn't an array.